# Ajax get return more classes with same name

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm using jQuery's `.get()` function to fetch another page (with greasemonkey). However I still can't get my code to work properly.

```
$.get('/events', function(data) { 
    var info = $(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').html();
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

`data` contains the page I requested but `info` only contains one element `.eventtitle.notread`. You can see this in the HTML code below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2351446"  /></td>
        <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle notread'>
            <a name="event2351446" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2351446#event2351446">Text 1</a>            </td>
        <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 21:12:12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2351440"  /></td>
        <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle '>
            <a name="event2351440" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2351440#event2351440">Text 2</a>            </td>
        <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 21:11:38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2348501"  /></td>
        <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle '>
            <a name="event2348501" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2348501#event2348501">Text 3</a>            </td>
        <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 19:04:35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='eventchkbox' width="2%"><input type="checkbox" name="del[]" value="2348489"  /></td>
        <td colspan="2" class='eventtitle notread'>
            <a name="event2348489" style="position:relative;top:-135px;left:-8000px;">&nbsp;</a><a href="/events/page/1/2348489#event2348489">text 4</a>            </td>
        <td class="eventdate">09-06-2013 19:04:01</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My goal is to display all unread messages on another page (incl. time stamp). How can I get all the `.eventtitle.notread` classes from `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation :

> ***.html()***
>
> Get the HTML contents of the **first element** in the set of matched
>   elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

so :

```
$(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').html();
```

only gets the HTML of the **first element** that matches the selector, not all of them!

If you're trying to `append()` the elements to the DOM, you don't really need to get the HTML, but if for some reason you need the actual string of HTML that is returned, you would have to iterate :

```
var info = "";
$(data).find('.eventtitle.notread').each(function() {
   info += $(this).html();
});
```